# Is it Possible to Loop Through a Map of Grids in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt, grid, maps

## Problem

I've checked the contents of the Map, the response keys and even tried grabbing the Maps manually. For some reason though, it only lets me create one map, no matter which one I select.

## My Attempt

**OccupancyCheckView Class**

So basically I create an object which in turn creates this Map:

`private Map<String, Grid> resultGrids = new HashMap<String, Grid>(); //where String is the title of the grid`

After it is created, I simply allow the user to grab it:

```
public Map<String, Grid> getResultGrids() {
        return resultGrids;
    }
```

**DataRun Class**

I make an RPC call in another class and wait for the response:

```
public void onSuccess(Method method, Response response) 
            {   
                occupancyCheckView = new OccupancyCheckView(response.getResult()); //This simply passes a list of two strings which creates the titles and grids and puts them in a Map<String, Grid>

                Map<String, Grid> resultGrids = occupancyCheckView.getResultGrids(); //I've checked the contents by dumping the WidgetName.toString() to the screen and BOTH grids are there yet I can't seem to call both of them at the same time

        //so this is where I try accessing both grids

                for( String Name : response.getResult() ) { 
                    Label gridTitle = new Label(String.valueOf(resultGrids.containsKey(Name))); //both return back as true
                    gridTitle.setStyleName("gridTitle");
                    mainPanel_.add(gridTitle);
                    mainPanel_.add(resultGrids.get(Name)); //accesses the Map<String, Grid>
                    testMap.add(resultGrids.get(Name));
                    echo.setText("No Data");
                }

                //mainPanel_.add(resultGrids.get("FirstResponse")); 
                //mainPanel_.add(resultGrids.get("SecondResponse"));

            }
```

I'm having no compilation errors. Everything works when I print the various parts to the screen (ask me if you want me to check for anything). On that last part where I commented out the two manual adding of the Grids, if I leave one or both in, it still only ever displays one grid, no matter which one I select.

## EDIT

How I create the grids:

```
private Grid occupancyGrid;

<Snip>

private void createResultGrid(List<String> gridName){

    occupancyGrid = new Grid(17,17);

    for (String Name_ : gridName){
    Label title = new Label();
    title.setText(Name_); 
    title.setStyleName("gridTitle"); //TODO style this

    for (int index=1;  index < occupancyGrid.getColumnCount(); index++){
        occupancyGrid.setWidget(0, index, new HTML("Cx"+Integer.toHexString(index-1)));
    }

    for (int index=1;  index < occupancyGrid.getRowCount(); index++){
        occupancyGrid.setWidget(index, 0, new HTML("Cx"+Integer.toHexString(index-1)));
    }

    resultLabels.put(Name_, title);
    resultGrids.put(Name_, occupancyGrid);
}
}
```

Comment: If you haven't done it already, could you check that the keys are really different and not the same?

Comment: @Kristjan Veskimäe Already done, the keys returned are `"FirstResponse"` and `"SecondResponse"`

Comment: @KristjanVeskimäe This is why I'm very confused....

Comment: Could you try adding break after in the end of your for-loop for( String Name : response.getResult() ) { 
...
break;
} Maybe you always leave the second map as the selected value so there is no way of changing it? If the for-cycle is iterated only once, it should leave only the first one which should be different

Comment: @KristjanVeskimäe - also the `//both return back as true` part would have returned a false value

Comment: @KristjanVeskimäe Surely though , if I comment out the for loop and just manually add the two maps like I did below, then it should have worked right?

Comment: Maybe try adding the first one mainPanel_.add(resultGrids.get("FirstResponse")); and afterwards the second one and see if there is difference. I have a gut feeling that you are using some API incorrectly.

Comment: @KristjanVeskimäe I think you could be right, I've added the code in where I create the Grids - it could be in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that you add both grids, but the second one is displayed on top of the first one. This may happen if your mainPanel_ is a LayoutPanel, for example.

Try adding both grids to a FlowPanel and then add this FlowPanel to your mainPanel_, or, if the mainPanel_ is a LayoutPanel, set the position of each grid when you add it.

Comment: You were correct, I instead created a FlowPanel and it worked. Thanks.